# How to save user by using form-data in spring boot rest & postman?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, postman

I am developing a spring boot Rest API for login and registration. I was able to save the data in the database by using @RequestBody from the body of a postman as raw data. But I want to send form data from the postman with every field. In this case which annotation should I use in the controller.

If anyone has a simple example, that would be great!

Please check the image :

[image: https://i.imgur.com/BWU63rK.png]

Dao Class -

```
@Repository
public class CustomerDaoImpl implements CustomerDao {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
public List<Customer> getCustomers() {

    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(); 
    
    Query<Customer> query = session.createQuery("from Customer", 
                                                Customer.class);
    
    List<Customer> customers = query.getResultList();
    
    return customers;
}

@Override
public Customer getCustomer(int id) {
    
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(); 

    Customer customer = session.get(Customer.class, id);
    
    return customer;
}

@Override
public void saveCustomer(Customer theCustomer) {
    
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    
    session.saveOrUpdate(theCustomer);

}

@Override
public void deleteCustomer(int Id) {

    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    
    Query query = session.createQuery("Delete from Customer where id=:customerId");
    
    query.setParameter("customerId", Id);
    
    query.executeUpdate();
}

@Override
public Customer getCustomer(String emailId, String password) {
    Customer customer = null;
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Query<Customer> query = session.createQuery("from Customer where emailId=:emailId and "
            + " password=:password");
    
    query.setParameter("emailId", emailId);
    query.setParameter("password", password);
    
    List<Customer> list = query.getResultList();
    
    try {
        return customer = list.get(0);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
        return null;
    }
 }

}
```

POJO Class -

```
    import java.sql.Timestamp;



    @Entity
    @Table(name="tbl_user_register")
    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY) 
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)

    public class Customer {

    @Id
    @Column(name="user_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name="email_id")
    private String emailId;
    
    @Column(name="mobile")
    private String mobile;
    
    @Column(name="business_name")
    private String businessName;
    
    @Column(name="address")
    private String address;
    
    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;
    
    @Column(name="created")
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Timestamp created;
    
    @Column(name="user_type")
    private int userType;
    
    @Column(name="parent_type")
    private int parentType;

    public Customer() {
        super();
    }
    
    public Customer(String name, String emailId, String mobile, String businessName, String address, String password,
            Timestamp created, int userType, int parentType) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.emailId = emailId;
        this.mobile = mobile;
        this.businessName = businessName;
        this.address = address;
        this.password = password;
        this.created = created;
        this.userType = userType;
        this.parentType = parentType;
    }



    public Customer(int id, String name, String emailId, String mobile, String businessName, String address,
            String password, Timestamp created, int userType, int parentType) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.emailId = emailId;
        this.mobile = mobile;
        this.businessName = businessName;
        this.address = address;
        this.password = password;
        this.created = created;
        this.userType = userType;
        this.parentType = parentType;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmailId() {
        return emailId;
    }

    public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }

    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public String getBusinessName() {
        return businessName;
    }

    public void setBusinessName(String businessName) {
        this.businessName = businessName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Timestamp getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(Timestamp created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    public int getUserType() {
        return userType;
    }

    public void setUserType(int userType) {
        this.userType = userType;
    }

    public int getParentType() {
        return parentType;
    }

    public void setParentType(int parentType) {
        this.parentType = parentType;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", emailId=" + emailId + ", mobile=" + mobile
                + ", businessName=" + businessName + ", address=" + address + ", password=" + password + ", created="
                + created + ", userType=" + userType + ", parentType=" + parentType + "]";
     }
   }
```

Controller -

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class CustomerController {

@Autowired
CustomerService customerService;
ResponseHandler response;   

@GetMapping("/customers")
public ResponseEntity<List<Customer>> getCustomers(){
            
    List<Customer> list = customerService.getCustomers();
    return new ResponseEntity<List<Customer>>(list, HttpStatus.OK);
}


@PostMapping(value="/login")
public Customer getCustomer(@RequestParam(value="emailId") String emailId, @RequestParam(value="password") String password) {
    

    Customer theCustomer = customerService.getCustomer(emailId, password);

    if(theCustomer == null) {
        throw new CustomerNotFoundException("Customer not found - "+emailId);
    }
    return theCustomer;
}



@PostMapping(value = "/customers", consumes=MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public Customer saveCustomer(@ModelAttribute Customer customer) {
    
    customerService.saveCustomer(customer);
    return customer;
    }

}
```

This is what I getting - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nygrs.jpg

Answer (score 1):

In a controller you can `getParameterMap()` which will give you all form data.

```
Map<String, String[]> parameterMap = request.getParameterMap();
```

or simply take a map as parameter

```
@RequestMapping("/yourmapping")
void method(@RequestParam HashMap<String, Object> formData){
   //rest your code
}
```

Comment: Okay, so I will use Map to get all the fields values from the postman form data but I still need to save that to the database. Cause I'm passing user bean to save method from dao class.

Comment: You can get from map and set it to user bean then pass user bean to dao.

Comment: Can you please show me some code? I'm kind of new to this.

Comment: Also, in one field I have send created time, how can I do that?

Comment: Can you please detail example, I still couldn't find solution

Answer (score 1):

You can provide `consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE` in your `@PostMapping`. `DataRequest` is model which will be including the data fields like name, email, etc. And also add getter setters in the DataRequest.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/readFile",consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public String readFile (@ModelAttribute DataRequest dataRequest)  {
    //DataRequest is the POJO in which you can mention the fields you want in the request
    return "done";      
}

@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class DataRequest {

    private String _id;
    private Date createTime;

    //add getter setters

}
```

Comment: In one field I have send created time, how can I do that?

Comment: send the createdTime as epoch time, and in pojo model except it as Date, for converting timestamp to epoch time you can use : https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: have you included getter setters in the pojo class?

Comment: I have included it but now its showing  "Content type 'application/json' not supported",

Comment: did you added application/json in header? If it is present then remove it

Comment: Yeah, I removed the application/json from header and it run perfectly but the problem is it saving null values in databsae.

Comment: add this above your pojo class(which will ignore the null value): `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`

Comment: Nope still not working, new object is creating but without all the fields

Comment: Try by adding - @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)     instead od  @JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)

Comment: Is it still adding null in db after adding `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` ?

Comment: yeah, it is saving null values and in the postman response those values are gets skipped now. So, only the Id and time is coming back in response not the complete object.

Comment: Complete object wont come as save operation only returns the id, not the complete object

Comment: Better approach is you should make different mapper for the incomming request, and use different class as model for saving purpose, you have to map the data from mapper class to the model class

Comment: my return type is Customer, as you can see in my code. So, it should return the complete object with Id. As, it was returned successfully when send it through raw data.

Comment: How can use model class and mapper class?

Comment: firstly, what happens when customer data is save, it returns only id, so the other data is null and due to @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) is omits all other fields

Comment: Can please explain how can I use model and mapper class?

Comment: See if you want all the data in the response and don't want to store null value in db, then first make a class in which you will accept the request data ( this class will be having @JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY))  and from the object of this class with the help of getter setter methods map datas value to another model class which you have made to store data in db(this class will be having @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)) , and then save the model class in db

Answer (score 0):

Try this , hope so it will work, Same Scenario it was work for me.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/customers", consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public Customer saveCustomer( Customer customer) {

       customerService.saveCustomer(customer);
       return customer;
    }
}
```